# Kimono get data from <head> element

Tags: html, web-scraping, kimono

I'm currently scraping a page using [Kimono](https://www.kimonolabs.com/) and I've been unable to select `<head>` element and get any data from it. In particularly I'm looking for `<link>` element.

I have also tried to get full html and then parse it in app.
In that case api just wont't return raw html just inner text to app even if I check html from *Data Model View > Advanced > Attributes* dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

I had to check **Include Hidden Elements** in *Data Model View > Advanced > Attributes* then Kimono found it normally.